# LayoutBuilder not adapting to screen

Tags: flutter

Somewhere on the internet I found an ResponsiveWidget class that looked really interesting to me. I wanted to use it, but I can't make it work.The output on the console is OK. Is it only about updating the UI? I tried changing widget to stateful, but it didn't work. My goal is to change the layout when the user changes the width of his/her internet browser window. Maybe there is a better way to do it? On other pages of my app I achieved my goal by using if statements with "static bool isLargeScreen" methods, but I guess that is not very elegant way to do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget largeScreen;
  final Widget? mediumScreen;
  final Widget? smallScreen;

  const ResponsiveWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.largeScreen,
      this.mediumScreen,
      this.smallScreen})
      : super(key: key);

  static bool isLargeScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 1000;
  }

  static bool isMediumScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650 &&
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 1000;
  }

  static bool isSmallScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth > 1000) {
          print('large');
          return largeScreen;
        } else if (constraints.maxWidth <= 1000 &&
            constraints.maxWidth >= 650) {
          print('medium');
          return mediumScreen ?? largeScreen;
        } else {
          print('small');
          return smallScreen ?? largeScreen;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:elearning/components/crosspage_widgets/my_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../components/crosspage_widgets/responsive_widget.dart';

class NotificationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotificationsPage> createState() => _NotificationsPageState();
}

class _NotificationsPageState extends State<NotificationsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyScaffold(
      bodyWidget: ResponsiveWidget(
        largeScreen: Text('Large'),
        mediumScreen: Text('Medium'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you say "The output on the console is OK" it should work I would think? Or maybe are you using `ResponsiveWidget` in other parts of your app also? Then maybe you see their prints actually. As for why it maybe doesn't work is when your `ResponsiveWidget` has an ancestor that doesn't change size while the screen resizes. A `LayoutBuilder` triggers when its own available space changes, not necessarily when the screen size changes.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Somehow MyScaffold prevented LayoutBuilder from updating. I changed to this and now it works.           ResponsiveWidget(
      largeScreen: MyScaffold(bodyWidget: Text('Large')),
      mediumScreen: MyScaffold(bodyWidget: Text('Medium')),
    );